# Best way of basically doing a `where` clause in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to parse some JSON that is sent to me and it's all in the format of

```
[{key:value},{key2:value2}, ... ]
```

What would be the best way to get the value of `key2` in this? Is there a way to do it without doing a for loop?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use a for loop?

Comment: Someone's addicted to Linq!

Comment: @vol7 but they aren't guaranteed to be in order like that

Comment: @Earlz Why are you trying to avoid a for loop? For performance reasons? Also, what are you using to parse the JSON?

Comment: @rsb I just wanted somethign cleaner than a for loop

Comment: Okay, but something is going to use a for/while loop at some point.  To me an array of objects doesn't seem like the best data structure, what if you have objects with the same key, do you want to return the value for the first key found, or all the values (consider `[{foo:'bar'},{foo:'baz'},{bar:'foo'}]`)

Comment: The question is ambiguous, to say at least. JSON provided in the example is an array of objects, but those objects are not of the same type (although they could be), considering they have different properties/keys, and the question is "What would be the best way to get the value of key2 in this?". However, you could convert that string into a JS array and use `.filter()` on the array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [Select](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#select) function from the [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) library.

Comment: For reference, my end result ended up looking like `var value2 = _.detect(data, function(d) { return d.key2 != undefined; }).key2;`

Comment: Doesn't this require loading a whole library (albeit small) for one specific case?

Comment: @vol7ron Yep.  But I bet once you use it in one place, you'll see other places you can use it.

Comment: It is pretty lightweight, so that's probably true.

Comment: @PaulPhillips but indirectly underscore function also use for loop :P

Comment: No need for an entire library, just to perform `filter()` on an array.

Comment: I think now it's the time to edit your answer ;) because you just used links and they are not available.

Answer (score 8):

Not really, but it wouldn't be hard to create a function to do that. However, it would indeed involves a `for` loop.

For the sake of completion, that would be the function:

```
function selectWhere(data, propertyName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i][propertyName] !== null) return data[i][propertyName];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
var key2value = selectWhere(data, "key2");
```

Comment: There are only a few things I don't like about this **1)** the use of `null`, **2)** the function name `selectWhere`; otherwise, good job, but *consider using a reverse-for loop*

Answer (score 7):

Javascript Array comes with methods that do just what you are asking for - find entries without you having to code a for-loop.

You provide them with the condition that you want.  A compact and convenient way to do that is with an arrow (or "lambda") function.  In your case, you are looking for array entries that have a specific key, so the arrow function could look something like this:

```
e => e.hasOwnProperty("key2")
```

---

Following the lead of some of the others, let's start with the assumption

```
var arr = [{key:"value"}, {key2:"value2"}, {key3:"value3"}]
```

---

If you expect that at most one member of the array has the key you want, you can use the `find()` function.  It will test each array member until it finds one where your condition is true, and return it.  If none are true, you'll get `undefined`.

```
var foundentry = arr.find(e => e.hasOwnProperty("key2"))
```

Either `foundentry` will be `undefined` or it will be the `{key2:"value2"}` that you are looking for, and can extract `value2` from it.

---

If `arr` can have more than one entry with the key that you are looking for, then instead of `find()` use `filter()`.  It gives back an array of entries that meet your criteria.

```
var foundarray = arr.filter(e => e.hasOwnProperty("key2"))
```

Comment: This is the best answer now. The find and filter methods were likely not available in 2011.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery grep() is a good analog for a Where clause:

```
var array = [{key:1},{key:2}, {key:3}, {key:4}, {key:5}];

var filtered = jQuery.grep(array, function( item, index ) {
  return ( item.key !== 4 && index > 1 );
});
```

Your filtered array will then contain two elements,

```
 [{key:3}, {key:5}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with an array, but you can make an associative array like object with it. Once you make it, you can use it like hash.

```
var arr = [{key:value},{key2:value2}, ... ], obj = {};

for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    $.extend(obj, arr[i]);
}

console.log(obj.key2); // value2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **.filter()** method for this object array, for example in your case:

```js
var objArray = [{key:"Hello"},{key2:"Welcome"} ];
var key2Value=objArray.filter(x=>x.key2)[0].key2;
```

Comment: this will be a SELECT not a WHERE

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that prototype's the Array object.  ***Note:*** this is shown for example - `find` is not a good name for this function, and this probably will not be needed for all arrays

Instead, consider just using the function definition and creating a function like `getObjVal`, calling like `getObjVal(arr,'propName')`, similar to LaurenT's answer.

#### Given

---

```
var arr = [{key:'value'},{key2:'value2'}];
```

#### Definition

---

```
// for-loop example
Array.prototype.find = function (prop){
                          for(var i=this.length; i--; )
                             if (typeof this[i][prop] !== 'undefined')
                                return this[i][prop];
                          return undefined;
                       }

// for-each loop example
Array.prototype.find = function (prop){
                          for (var i in this)
                             if ( this.hasOwnProperty(i) && typeof this[i][prop] !== "undefined" ) 
                                return this[i][prop];
                          return undefined;
                       }
```

#### Usage

---

```
console.log( arr.find('key2') );  // 'value2'
console.log( arr.find('key3') );  // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex - no for loop:

```
var key2Val = jsonString.match(/\{key2:[^\}]+(?=\})/)[0].substring("{key2:".length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Heyas. You can use the lodash library's ***.reduce()*** or **.transform()** functions to implement this. Lodash is more modular than underscore (Underscore around 5kb, Lodash around 17kb), but is generally lighter because you only include the specific modules you need 
(please see: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9078590 for discussion). For this demonstration I will import the entire module (generally not an issue on the backend):
I wrote these snippets for either scenario which handle both numeric and non-numeric arguments.

https://lodash.com/docs#reduce

https://lodash.com/docs#transform

Pull in lodash:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

**_.reduce() to where clause:**

```
var delim = ' WHERE ', where = _.isEmpty(options) ? '' : _.reduce(options, function(r, v, k) {
    var w = r + delim + k + '=' + (_.isNumber(v) ? v : ("'" + v + "'"));
    delim = ' AND ';
    return w;
}, '');
```

**_.transform() to where clause:**

```
var where = _.isEmpty(options) ? '' : ' WHERE ', delim = '';
_.transform(options, function(r, v, k) {
        where = where + delim + k + '=' + (_.isNumber(v) ? v : ("'" + v + "'"));
        delim = ' AND ';
    });
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Top answer does the job. Here's a one liner version of it using lodash (same as underscore for the most part):

```
var result = _.filter(data, _.partialRight(_.has, 'key2'));
```

In lodash, select is just an alias for filter. I pass it the data array filled with objects. I use `_.has` as the the filter function since it does exactly what we want: check if a property exists.

`_.has` expects two args:

```
_.has(object, path)
```

Since `_.has` expects two arguments, and I know one of them is always constant (the path argument). I use the `_.partialRight` function to append the constant `key2`. `_.partialRight` returns a new function that expects one argument: the object to inspect. The new function checks if `obj.key2` exists.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(stringJSON);
var value = parsedJSON['key2'];
```

Comment: are you having an issue with JSON.parse()?  Maybe try parsedJSON.key2

Comment: K, so I see you are using an array instead of valid JSON... So if you pass the function a valid string, you'll get where you want to go.  JSON.parse() isn't included in some browsers, especially mac and also older.  You can however include it manually.  It returns an object tho, not an array.  ANd you may have to play with it a little, but I'm sure what you're looking for involves JSON.parse().Nice that I get the neg one one tho, instead of the guy who gives you a loop when the whole idea is not to use a loop.

Comment: it is valid JSON. I validated it. Maybe my example is bad. Here is a clip of the real data: `[{"employername":"FosTech"},{"from":"3/14/2008"},{"to":"5/1/2011"},{"worktype":"programmin" ... ]}`

Comment: K, correct you are sir... but you have a JSON array, not a JSON object. Arrays begin with square brackets, and objects curly braces. More specifically, you have an array of objects or an array of object literals using JSON notation. One JSON object representing your data would look like...`{"employername":"FosTech","from":"3/14/2008","to":"5/1/2011","worktype":"‌​programmin",...}`

Comment: K, correct you are sir... but you have a JSON array, not a JSON object. Arrays begin with square brackets, and objects curly braces. More specifically, you have an array of objects or an array of object literals using JSON notation. One JSON object representing your data would look like...`{"employername":"FosTech","from":"3/14/2008","to":"5/1/2011","worktype":"‌​programmin",...}`  Parsing a string formatted as an object would allow you to then reference that data set as an object using the code above