# How do I put two conditions into a foreach statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to teach myself javascript while fixing someone elses programme.  I have a foreach statement which I want to have two confitional elements, how do I structure this as the code I am using is returning an error

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Journals.Where(m => m.ProcedureId != null && m.Hidden !=1))
```

Comment: Isn't this LINQ/C#?

Comment: That's not javascript... perhaps Razor Engine on a ASPNET application in .NET?

Comment: IT's not JS. There is no `@foreach`. Do you use some pre-processor?

Comment: it's super weird JS, you may mis-work on something else

Comment: What library is giving you the where function?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Hmm, I'll follow up on what language this is in though I have managed to sort out the syntax in the mean time through some experimentation

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use foreach in JavaScript you can do it like this:

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array.forEach(function(element) {
 console.log(element);
});
```

If you want conditions for each iteration just include an if-statement:

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array.forEach(function(element) {
    if(element !== 'a' && element !== 'c'){
       // Would only return 'b'
       console.log(element);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the underscore select function or write your own function as suggested in this question: [Best way of basically doing a `where` clause in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959530/best-way-of-basically-doing-a-where-clause-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If this is indeed Javascript, it seems like what you want to do is take an array and return a subset of the array that matches the conditions and then perform an action for each item of that subset. 
In order to do this you might use `Array#Filter` before using forEach.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```js
// Assuming Models.Journals is an array or objects with
// ProcedureId and Hidden fields

Models.Journals.filter(m => m.ProcedureId != null && m.Hidden !=1).forEach(...)
```